# JNI - Is it possible to replace the instantiation of a class with a different class?

Tags: java, c++, dll, java-native-interface

I apologize for the undescriptive title, but I'm unsure how to summarize this in one sentence. What I have is an older DLL file which is calling everything from the default package in java. I can't import these classes from the default package without reflection and I need to refactor them as well. The problem is I don't have the source code for the DLL and it is impossible to get it. I have created an intermediate dll that redirects all the method calls. For example in Java I call refactoredMethod which calls refactoredMethod inside the intermediate DLL, and the intermediate DLL calls originalMethod inside the original DLL. This works fine up until the original DLL tries to do something like this:

```
jclass cls = (*env)->FindClass(env, "UnpackagedClass");
```

But obviously, since I've refactored this class and moved it into a package, this fails. So I'm wondering if it is at all possible to replace all instances of

```
jclass cls = (*env)->FindClass(env, "UnpackagedClass");
```

that are inside the original DLL with

```
jclass cls = (*env)->FindClass(env, "com/test/RefactoredClass");
```

from inside the intermediate DLL. By the way, before someone says anything, it is not possible to rewrite the original DLL due to it's size, it doesn't require any maintenance besides this, and I have permission to use it. Thank you.

Comment: Where is the DLL getting `UnpackagedClass` from?  Assuming it's a jar file, can you replace the jar file with one that has a `class UnpackagedClass extends com/test/RefactoredClass {...}`?

Comment: Maybe you could try dirty things with the class loader...

Answer (score 0):

If you have no chance to change original DLL, think about using Adapter pattern.

This pattern is used in case you want to adapt one interface to another one.

I know this will probably create lots of classes in your Java implementation, but if you have no other choice, I'd go that way.

Take a look at supper simple adapter that is accessing class from inside package:

https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook/tree/master/recipes/recipeNo028